# JHipster and Karma: Error when i launch npm run test:watch

Tags: testing, karma-runner, jhipster

I try to create my unit tests in my project with Jhipster 4.3 with Angular2.

But when i launch:

```
 npm run test:watch
```

I have an error when i open http://localhost:9876/# and i can't debug my test:

```
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!
```

I Have two questions:

- Is it normal if i have this error with Jhipster default configuration?
- How can I debug my test with Karma and the preprocessors with breackpoint in the chrome dev toolbar?

.

```
preprocessors: {'spec/entry.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']}
```

---

**Alternative solution **UPDATE**:**

Actually, i launch the @angular-cli alternative:

```
ng test
```

But i can't correctly debug my test with breackpoint.

---

Thanks for your help!